# Feedburner RSS url variable for number of items in feed?

Tags: rss, feed, feedburner

I'm parsing another blog's content by reading their Feedburner RSS feed...

Example: http://feeds.feedburner.com/WebsiteNameHere?fmt=xml

...but the feed only returns 10 items. Is there a URL variable to override the number of items returned in the feed?

I have already tried the following to return 25 items: n=25, no=25, num=25, q=25, max=25, max_results=25, and items=25.

...any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such parameter available to override or limit the number of items through a Feedburner delivered RSS feed.

The count of items that appear are set by the site's original feed. If that raw version (before it is wrapped around Feedburner) allows you to add parameters to adjust the number of items, that may be possible.

But no, you can't do it after it's been burned.

Also note going through the Feedburner API route is off since [Google has shut that down](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/05/spring-cleaning-for-some-of-our-apis.html).

Comment: This answer seems incorrect. For instance, in a google sheet you can ImportFeed with a variable count of items.

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093337?hl=en : If num_items is not specified, all items currently published on the feed are returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nItems as the parameter. For example:

```
nItems=40
```

It works in our case, but I dont know the max limit.